# Auto increment variable in while loop

Tags: php, html

I have a variable that is a string with `divs` in html.

I'm trying to include a number in it that starts at one and auto increments so that each `div` is numbered in ascending order.

This is my while:

```
while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$catname9 = $row9["catname"];
$statusid9 = $row9["id"];
$i = 1;
```

This is my string that I echo repeatedly until it reaches the end of my called SQL table:

```
$list9 .= '<div id="each9" style="margin-top:3px" onclick="moveTo(\'.main\', '.$i.');"></div>
```

Then I echo:

```
<?php echo $list9; ?>
```

So how do I make the first one 1 then the second repeat 2 and the third repeat 3?

Comment: instead of `$i = 1;` try `$i++;` which is shorter version of `$i = $i + 1;`

Answer (score 11):

Set up your while loop like so:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    // looped logic here

    $i++;
}
```

The important thing here is to initialize the counter **before** the loop, and increment it on each iteration.

You can also increment it by other amounts if you want. Just replace `$i++` with `$i += 2`;

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the variable by `$i=1` like:

```
$i = 1; 
while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

echo $i; // will print 1,2,3 to number of count.
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will have to declare the index variable before the while loop.
If you declare it inside, it will be a new variable each time it iterates.
When that is done, you will need to increment the variable for each iteration, this can be done by either `$i++` or `$i+=1`.

If you wish it to start with 1 and the increase, set it to 1 from start and increase it by 1 at the *end* of the loop.

Like:

```
$index = 1;
while(...) {
  // Do stuff...
  $index++; // increase.
}
```

Comment: I think a `for` loop is unnecessary here. It overcomplicates the situation. `while` and `foreach` are better choices when it comes to array traversal.

Comment: Yes I would personally go with the while loop here. Not really sure why I added the for-loop part, been thinking about it since i did, ill remove that part to not cause confusion ;)

Comment: Really like this answer as you not only solve the problem, you took the time to explain why the iterator should be declared outside of the while loop and what happens if it's included inside instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $i++;
} 
echo $i;
```

Comment: Could you explain how this adds anything more than the other answers given to this question?